# Thru jenkins pipeline or jenkins file - how can i check node status before i start main stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Thru jenkins pipeline or jenkins file - how can i check node status before i start main stages ?

I tried to use jenkins cli but having authorization issues (i am not an admin and have no user and password).

I am getting json result for node information -

```
localhost:8080/node1/api/json
```

I want to reach and read entities in that json report

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure why you want that.. usually you use labels on the build agents to pick one that fits.

Comment: @StephenKing I need it due to projects scales in my company

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you mean by "project scales," what specific datum/data you want to read, and what logic you want to apply? There may be a "Jenkinsy" way without relying on querying the raw data.